# Use iphone or android as external mic for macbook using bluetooth

Tags: iphone, mac, microphone, android

Is there a way I can use an iPhone/Android phone as an external microphone for my Mac? Ideally without a cable i.e. bluetooh/wifi.

Edit:

Since this hasn't been answered yet, I would be okay with using cables too if people know how to do that.

Comment: If you have GarageBand, you could use the jam sessions. It uses both wifi and Bluetooth.

Comment: @bret: Could you elaborate? I just want an to use the phone as an external mic that can be held close to the mouth... It's not for purposes of making music necessarily, but I don't mind GarageBand if it allows doing this somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Using a cable, your iPhone can be an audio source by using the built-in Audio MIDI setup.  Plug in your phone and click enable.
[image]
Next make sure your mac is set to use the device for input.
[image]
Then on your phone select audio output to Dock connector.  Now any audio from your phone will be sent to your Mac.  To use it as a microphone you now need to use an app that lets you feed back your mic.  There are many apps that do that, I use https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microphone-free-vonbruno/id1070812067?mt=8 since it is free and simple.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the asker specifically requested a wireless link.

Comment: Could you give more detail regarding "on your phone select audio output to Dock connector"? I'm not seeing this on iPhone.